# Difference between times

Tags: ruby

I'm using the [time_difference](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference) gem in Ruby 2.2.3 which works great but while it can tell me the difference between two times it can't tell me if that difference is positive or negative.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'time_difference'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> t1 = "11:30"
=> "11:30"
irb(main):003:0> t2 = "11:20"
=> "11:20"
irb(main):004:0> TimeDifference.between(t1, t2).in_minutes
=> 10.0
```

Can anyone help me get my desired result (In this case -10 Min) The reason for this I have to compare two times that are delivered as `"HH:MM"`so I can find out how early or late something is in minutes so need to know if its + or -.

**Update with answer:**

With [@Jesus's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333436/jesus-castello) answer I was able to get the correct output. I then needed to be able to deal with times that span midnight so this was the code I ended up with;

```
def convert_to_minutes(seconds)
    (seconds / 60).round
end

def time_keeper(actual_time, planned_time, ssd)
    today = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    tt_time = "#{ssd} #{planned_time}"
    real_time = "#{today} #{actual_time}"
    t1 = Time.parse(tt_time)
    t2 = Time.parse(real_time)
    time_output = convert_to_minutes(t2 - t1)
end
```

Comment: It's not going to be straightforward due to the following line:

https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference/blob/master/lib/time_difference.rb#L65

The call to `.abs` means that the result will always be positive.

Comment: might sound stupid from my limited experience but, cant I just drop that call? Otherwise I'm open to another way to get the same result.

Comment: It all depends on your parameters. Will they contain "am" and "pm" or will they be 24-hour times? Could they be from different days?

Comment: They won't ever contain am or pm and will always be 24hr times. They could span across 1 day but that's about the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using the time `Time` class an option? If it is this might be a possible solution:

```
require 'time'

def convert_to_minutes(seconds)
  (seconds / 60).round
end

t1 = Time.parse("11:30")
t2 = Time.parse("11:20")

difference = convert_to_minutes(t2 - t1)
```

Comment: This works - but can I get rid of the trailing `.0` so it reports in round min's only? `-10`

Comment: I've just hit a midnight spanning issue.. If a reported time correctly spans midnight I end up being 1440 min early or late. Is there an easy fix with your code?

Comment: Can you provide an example please? The two times you are using.

Comment: 23:59 & 00:01 results in -1438

Comment: Ok, the problem is that both times are being compared on the basis that they are on the same day. Do you have access to the day? In that case doing something like `t1 = Time.parse("1/1/2015 23:59")` and `t2 = Time.parse("2/1/2015 00:01")` returns the correct value.

Answer (score -2):

```
x = TimeDifference.between(t1, t2).in_minutes
if t1 > t2
  x = x * -1
end
```

Comment: `"9:00" < "10:00"` returns `false`

Comment: Yes. As I understand the question they want to make the difference negative if it means going back, i.e. t1 is AFTER t2. If t1 is 09:00 and t2 is 10:00 that is a positive differenced, those the sign is not changed. The `if` statement does nothing if the change is positive.

Comment: @jason where is anyone using the comparison you posted above and how does it relate to my answer. You comment has no meaning to this discussion. This answers the OP's question within the parameters they have given. If there are edge cases that fail then they need to make their requirements more specific.

Comment: The problem is that `"9:00" < "10:00"` returns `false`, but `"10:00" < "11:00"` returns `true`. The `<` and `>` operators are inconsistent with strings in that format. I would hardly call 2-digit hours "edge cases".

Comment: OK, I see your point now. Never hurts to explain your reasoning.

Comment: I should have explained why that was relevant. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also the OP says it is 24 hour time (what I assumed since there was no sign) and "9:00" is not valid 24 hour time.